# word autocomplete(word suggestion) in textarea

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql

In my code, I use one text area which gives word suggestion(AutoComplete) and this text area takes the value of words suggestion from MySQL database table. But this textarea gives word suggestion only first word in textarea whenever I type the second word in textarea it does not give any suggestion so how to fix this code for its gives suggestion in all word in textarea.

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<script>
   $(function() {
     $("#skill_input").autocomplete({
         source: "search.php",
         minLength: 1,
         select:function (event,ui) {
             event.onkeyup();
             $('#skill_input').value;

         }
     });
   });
</script>
<p>your skills:<textarea name="skill_input" id="skill_input" rows="10" ></textarea></p>
```

**PHP Code:**

```
$db = new mysqli($dbHost, $dbUsername, $dbPassword, $dbName);
$query = $db->query("SELECT * FROM skills WHERE skill LIKE '%".$searchTerm."%' ORDER BY skill ASC");
$skillData = array();
if($query->num_rows > 0){
  while($row = $query->fetch_assoc()){
    $data['id'] = $row['id'];
    $data['value'] = $row['skill'];
    array_push($skillData, $data);
  }
}

echo json_encode($skillData);
```

Answer (score 1):

Hello @Love Barot in order for the suggestions to show for the second word also you need to have data in that form

Please check the following fiddle in which I contain "two" as data and "two three" as data so when I type "tw" it shows two as the suggestion and when I type "th" after two it shows suggestion "three" since data of that form is present.

```
 [JS fiddle link](https://jsfiddle.net/hp_issei/0gf294vy/2/)
```

And that's the reason you are not getting suggestions for the second word.

Comment: hello @Hp_issei as per your suggestion I type first word A in textarea then its give suggestion like ActionScript its ok but I want whenever I type enter,space or goto next line and after I type A or something different then its not give any suggestion. I want its give suggestion in all and each word in text area..so how to fix this problem....?

Comment: Please check the [Autocomplete docs](https://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/).